# webpack alias not resolving as expected within React class function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, webpack

I'm trying to play an audio file from a dynamic data object, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
App.js:12 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
  at webpackMissingModule (App.js:12)
  at App._this.playAudio (App.js:12)
  at onClick (App.js:29)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:201)
  at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:466)
  at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:488)
  at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:586)
  at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:597)
  at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:567)
  at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:728)
  at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:737)
  at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4201)
  at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:12537)
  at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1939)
  at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4282)
  at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:12592)
  at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1958)
  at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4259)
```

Here's my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './App.scss';
import characterData from 'api/characterData';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [...characterData]
  }

  playAudio = srcFile => {
    const importedAudioFile = require(srcFile);
    const characterAudio = new Audio(importedAudioFile);
    characterAudio.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.characterCard}>
        {this.state.characters.map(({ audio, name }) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={styles.characterCard}
              key={name}
              onClick={() => this.playAudio(audio)}
            >
              <h3>{name}</h3>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`characterData.js` looks like this:

```
export default [
    {
        name: 'Chewbaca',
        hp: 120,
        strength: 5,
        image: 'images/chewie.jpg',
        audio: 'audio/chewie.mp3'
    },
    {
        name: 'Darth Vader',
        hp: 150,
        strength: 7,
        image: 'images/darth.png',
        audio: 'audio/darthbreath.mp3'
    },
    {
        name: 'Princess Leia',
        hp: 160,
        strength: 8,
        image: 'images/leia.jpg',
        audio: 'audio/leiasound.mp3'
    },
    {
        name: 'Obi Wan Kenobi',
        hp: 115,
        strength: 6,
        image: 'images/obiwan.png',
        audio: 'audio/obisound.mp3'
    },
];
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
└── src
    ├── api
    ├── audio
    |  ├── chewie.mp3
    |  ├── darthbreath.mp3
    |  ├── leiasound.mp3
    |  ├── obisound.mp3
    |  └── tie.mp3
    ├── components
    ├── containers
    |  └── App
    ├── images
    ├── index.js
    ├── styles
    └── utils
```

I ejected from `create-react-app` and both webpack configs are nearly identical with the exception of implementing `sass-loader`, and the edits to `resolve.alias` which look like:

```
...
alias:  {
  // Support React Native Web
  // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
  'react-native': 'react-native-web',

  // Custom Aliases
  ...aliases
},
...
```

`const aliases = require('./aliases');` is at the top of each of my webpack configurations and `aliases.js` looks like:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'api': path.resolve('src/api'),
  'audio': path.resolve('src/audio'),
  'components': path.resolve('src/components'),
  'containers': path.resolve('src/containers'),
  'images': path.resolve('src/images'),
  'variables': path.resolve('src/styles/variables.scss'),
  'mixins': path.resolve('src/styles/mixins.scss')
}
```

If I hardcode `srcFile` in `App.playAudio` to `'audio/chewie.mp3'`, it works. Unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to use `characterData` as a mock for an API the quick (but not really extensible way) would be to just require the audio file in your export from `characterData`. The problem you're running into is that webpack when it runs at build time doesn't know what to bundle for you. If you need resources which you aren't explicitly requiring you could checkout webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context)

Comment: Thanks! I used `require('audio/chewie.mp3')` in the actual API mock file and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with alias, but with dynamic import, try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-file-require